# node.js express - attempting the redis MULTI / EXEC command

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I have a noob question. 
I'm writing my first node.js / express REST API. For one of my POST methods, the clients can send multiple "records" to save in the DB in one shot.

i'm trying to write my MULTI / EXEC logic... use the samples in the readme file that comes with the redis client.

But I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's how I write to my hash manually via redis-cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset widget:widget1 00:00:00_00:00:00 123@testmeout.com
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

This is what my code looks like

**common.js**

```
var redis = require('redis');
exports.redis = redis.createClient('6379','10.2.2.2');
```

**widgets.js**

```
var common = require('./common');
var redis = common.redis;

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    // do a bunch of stuff. 
    // multi test.  all hardcoded for now until i understand how it works.
    redis.multi([
        ["hset", "widget:widget1", "00:00:00_00:00:00", "123@testmeout.com",redis.print ],
        ["hset", "widget:widget2", "00:00:00_00:00:00", "222@willywonka.com", redis.print]
    ]).exec(function (err, replies) {
            if (err ){
                    console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(replies);
            }
    });
```

On the console, I see

```
 [ undefined, undefined ]
```

for the "replies" output.  I don't get any errors.  But I also can't see any of my hashes in the database.  I tried this query on the redis-cli to verify that nothing was added to the database:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match widget:w* count 10000000
1) "0"
2) (empty list or set)
```

**EDIT 1**

As a test I tried to add a HGETALL call in my multi.  and it works.  Notice the multi code now:

```
redis.multi([
    ["hgetall", "widget:7449890"],
    ["hset", "widget:widget1", "00:00:00_00:00:00", "123@testmeout.com",redis.print ],
    ["hset", "widget:widget2", "00:00:00_00:00:00", "222@willywonka.com", redis.print]
]).exec(function (err, replies) {
        if (err ){
                console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(replies);
        }
});
```

Which returns the following on the console:

```
[ { '00:00:00_00:00:00': 'johndoe@test.net' },
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

Also the other interesting artifact I found is this - I turned on redis-cli monitoring as my node js app runs and I see the following queries being made against the database:

```
1476985090.048093 [0 10.238.36.117:36069] "multi"
1476985090.048118 [0 10.238.36.117:36069] "hgetall" "widget:7449890"
1476985090.048137 [0 10.238.36.117:36069] "exec"
1476985092.800405 [0 10.238.36.118:6379] "PING"
```

I guess thereby proving that the HSET commands are not being executed at all.

I also tried changing hset to hsetall ... but it's the same results.  No errors but also no set command being executed.

Comment: A typo, you should issue `scan 0 match widget:myw* count 10000000` or `keys widget:myw*`.

Comment: (In your manual example the key is different from the one in code).

Comment: yeah sorry, that was just a typo as i was writing the post, vs a typo in the actual tests i'm running.  I've fixed the post.

Comment: i figured it out!  my bad.  the code was running against a read only slave of the redis database.  doh!  sorry for the noise guys